# How to implement firebaseUI in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I new to IOS Development.I am basically  android developer

I want to implement firebaseUI for login using mobile number and email

I got doc  here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui?authuser=0.  But i am getting compiletime error..below I mention

My **AppDelegate** file

[image]

my **ViewController** class

[image]

if I comment this line `authUI.delegate = self`  above line getting  wrong below I add image...
[image]

Comment: Use `authUI?.delegate = self`. This is optional chaining. Another thing, if you click on the red dot, it will apply a fix-it which is sometimes helpful.

Comment: which ui you need to implement phone auth?

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen oh I am very sorry..by mistake I did it....and also I want to show the error message so I posted screenshot

Answer (score 0):

authUI is a Swift [optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional), which means it can be nil (null). In order to use optionals, you must unwrap them with the '?' sign. So your code can be simply fixed with:

```
authUI?.delegate = self
```

If authUI is nil, the code will do nothing, whereas in Java it would cause a null pointer exception. You may unwrap it with '!' instead, which will cause a runtime error if authUI is nil.

Tip: you can click on the red error or yellow warning icons to see and apply suggested fixes, much like Alt-Enter on Android Studio. Do not rely too much on those, sometimes the automatic fixes become a mess. :)